# Visualizing CTC - is it related to a "periodic wick rotation"?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, wick-rotation, closed-timelike-curve

As far as I understand Wick rotation, it means the mathematical transformation $$ ct → jct $$
Where $j$ is imaginary unit. While reading on CTC (closed timelike curves) in the Gödel metric I came across this particular diagram of rotating light cone (the orthogonal $x-t$ axes are essentially rotating beyond a specific radius). Does this mean that after every 90 degree rotation space and time periodically switch their roles?
$$
(x,t)→(-ct,x/c)→(-x,-t)→(ct,-x/c)→(x,t)
$$
Secondly, is this "role-switching" anyhow related to that inside a black hole? And thirdly, can CTCs inside a rotating black hole be explained on similar lines?